# Disable Portrait interface in iOS 6

Tags: uiinterfaceorientation, ios6

In my UIViewController

```
- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscape;
}

-(BOOL) shouldAutorotate {
    return NO;
}
```

I should only support Landscape orientation in iOS 6. But it didn't work. It still working auto rotation.

How to fix disable autorotate in iOS 6 ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found a solution.

I am using viewcontroller with UINavigationController. So, I need to change supportedInterfaceOrientations in UINavigationController.

```
@interface UINavigationController (autorotate)

@end

@implementation UINavigationController (autorotate)


- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscape;
}

-(BOOL) shouldAutorotate {
    return YES;
}

@end
```

Answer (score 3):

If your entire app will only support landscape, you can just skip the subclass and set your supported interface orientations to Landscape (left) and Landscape (right) in Info.plist